# Build a context-free grammar for a context-free language

Tags: context-free

A context-free language is defined by its description:

$L=(a^{2k} \space  b^n \space c^{2n} \mid k \geq 0, \space n > 0)$

For example:

$bcc, aabcc, aabbcccc, bbcccc$

**How to build a context-free grammar for this context-free language?**

I suppose that the order for generating any chain in this problem matters: 'b' will always stand after 'a' and 'c' - after 'b'. Is it so?

My attempts leaded to this solution:

$ S \rightarrow aaAbcc \mid bAcc \mid aabAcc $

$ A \rightarrow aa \mid bcc \mid λ $

Please correct me if I'm wrong or better offer your solution to this problem.

Comment: Why? This is a concrete problem that has its own conditions and solution and differs from the examples offered in that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ S \rightarrow EG $ , 
$ E \rightarrow aO \mid λ $ ,
$ O \rightarrow aE $ ,
$ F \rightarrow bFcc \mid λ $, 
$ G \rightarrow bFcc $ .
I am assuming $λ$ stands for empty string.

Better one:

$ S \rightarrow EF $ , 
$ E \rightarrow aO \mid λ $ ,
$ O \rightarrow aE $ ,
$ F \rightarrow bFcc \mid bcc $.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to me it's correct! But is it possible to move some conditions (including terminals) in the S rule? Like I was trying to do.

Comment: I was unable to move terminals to S because of the fact that number of a's and b's can be different. Although you may try it. If you are able to move them please let me know.

Comment: Slightly simpler, $S\rightarrow EF, E\rightarrow aaE \mid \lambda, F\rightarrow bFcc \mid bcc$.